# Looking for the best way to unwrap walls of an Architecture project

Tags: uv

I hope someone can give me a clue on this.

I been using Blender for a while doing architecture projects for Unreal engine

I am happy with the models but I feel stupid when it's time to unwrap it for UV mapping, so I always just make a smart UV projection.

In some cases it works but I want to make things better. I've seen lot of tutorials but they are either too simple like a cube (I understand perfectly how to unwrap a cube) or too complex, like a human head.

I split the house in wall sections with external an internal walls, but it just not clear to me where to put the seams before unwrapping the model.

This is the house I am working in

[image: House]

And this is one of the walls

[image: Walls]

Comment: Unwrapping well is something that depends on how you want to texture.  Maybe you can explain exactly why smart project isn't always working for you?

Comment: Attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail comments or answer

Comment: thanks for your answer Nathan. in this case is not really important because is just  white paint texture from inside and outiside. i just want to understand where to put the seams to unwrap it. i can do it with project from view but i want to use the seam method. i put a seam al around the out wall an other round the inner and separete the 16 faces of the windows with terrible results